# Xcode C++ Methods definition

Tags: c++, xcode

I got simple class

Entity.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string"
#include "MainComponent.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Entity
{
public:
    vector<MainComponent *> components;
    string id;
    Entity(string _id);
    Entity(string _id, vector<MainComponent *> _comp);
    ~Entity();
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(string _id) {
    id = _id;
}
Entity::Entity(string _id, vector<MainComponent *> _comp) {
    id = _id;
    components = _comp;

    cout <<  "Entity initialized" << endl;

};
Entity::~Entity() {};
```

I'm using

```
Entity* entity1 = new Entity("aaaa", vector<MainComponent *>{ new MovementComponent(pair<int, int>(10,10)) } );
```

And got this errors

[image]

Build would be successfull if in `.h` file i define methods like this with curly brackets:

```
Entity(string _id) {};
Entity(string _id, vector<MainComponent *> _comp) {};
~Entity() {};
```

But they wouldn't redefine in `.cpp`

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy-paste the errors as text into the question instead.

Comment: Did you link in the `Entity.o` i.e. in Xcode, did you include `Entity.cpp` in the build?

Comment: Glen i guess you right, but how to include .cpp files in Xcode project? I always saw including .h files only